# awk script error on solaris

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I have **following script** and trying to run it:

```
BEGIN {
  start = 0
}

{
  if (match($0, "<WorkflowProcess ")) {
    startTag++
  }  

  if ((startTag < 2) || (endTag == startTag)) {
    print
  }

  if (match($0, "</WorkflowProcess>")) {
    endTag++
  }
}
```

**However I always get this error:**

awk: syntax error near line 6

awk: illegal statement near line 6

awk: syntax error near line 10

awk: bailing out near line 10

Any thoughts? I have tried to convert it via dos2unix and also with tr -d '\r' but it's still the same issue. The input parameter is in my opinion corect when I am sending a fullpath with file name and extention (/export/home/test/file.txt). **All files have 0777.**

Comment: What happens if you overdose on semi-colons (`BEGIN { start=0; };`, etc.)?

Comment: Nothing, the same error.

Comment: What `awk` do you use?  and what system?  On my ubuntu 12.04 this runs fine.

Comment: System: SunOS SERVER_NAME 5.10 Generic_147440-09 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220

Comment: Sorry the Awk version I dont know :( even tried to google how to find out but... :-/

Comment: Have you tried nawk instead of awk?

Comment: @Alone89 try `awk --version`. I'm running version 4.0.1 on Fedora 18 and your script runs fine.

Comment: nawk error -syntax error at source line 1 context is >>> . <<< ... the awk --version do nothing :/

Comment: I tried that too  :) nothign happens....

Comment: One more shot: `awk -V`? You must be on a very old system.

Comment: How are you running your script `awk -f script.awk /export/home/test/file.txt`? `nawk -f script.awk /export/home/test/file.txt`?

Comment: Mode 0777 is **never** the correct file mode.

Answer (score 1):

*How* do you try to run that program?

If you use `awk "... all that program ..."`, then the shell will expand `$0` to its own path, which probably has a leading `/`... Although, now that I look at it, that should fail earlier with the internal `"`. Still, it would be useful to see the precise command line.

By the way, why are you calling `match`? It would be much more idiomatic to write:

```
awk '
    /<WorkflowProcess /  { ++startTag }
    startTag < 2 || startTag == endTag { print }
    /</WorkflowProcess>/ { ++endTag }
'
```

which avoids the explicit use of `$0` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

On SunOS `nawk` is often the better choice :

```
nawk -f script.awk /export/home/test/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, in the `BEGIN` rule you initialize `start`, not `startTag`, but then you increment `startTag` in the next rule. I know, this works in GNU awk and all, but maybe you should try initializing `startTag`.